# how to create one menu entry to display many modules

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'd like to display n modules when the users click on a menu entry. Is there any way to do something like that ? 
I could use sub-menus but I'd prefer to have 1 module for the "hot topics" of the menu entry, 3 or 4 modules for sub-categories of the menu entry and a last module displaying all the articles corresponding to the menu entry.

More precisely :
(sorry for not being clear and the line breaks.)
I have a category with sub-categories. Some of the articles are tagged as "HOT".
I want that when they click on 1 entry, users see :
- a list of the articles tagged as "HOT" (I have a module which do that)
- a list of selected sub-categories and the articles they contain presented as a table of content (I've got a module which do that)
- a list of all the articles.
When I create a menu entry, I can only select one type of content (category blog, category list etc.). Wrong ?
Thanks for your responses

jc

Comment: Please use line breaks to format your question. This way it is almost not understandable

Comment: Do you mean modules only with no component content?  You can show how ever many module you want on a given menu link, just select them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !
Go to Extensions -> Module Manager.
Edit each module you want to be displayed and go to Menu Assignement tab. In the Module Assignement pulldown menu, select "Only on the pages selected".
A list of all your menu entries is then displayed, you just have to select/deselect according to your needs.
Hence you can select as many modules as wanted to be displayed when users click on the choosen menu entry.
Cool !

Comment: You can also edit on the modules tab when creating/editing a menu item.